# Share from browser on the second try does not invoke my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I have a dictionary-type application that accepts, via an intent filter, arbitrary text shared from other apps, e. g. the browser. The intent filter is attached to a decicated activity ("Lookup") that does some posttranslation of the shared text and invokes my main activity. The lookup activity quietly closes.

I'm testing it with the system browser on Samsung Galaxy with Android 4.0.4, and here's a funny thing I notice. On the first try, it works as expected. I tap "Share", select my app as the target, the lookup activity is invoked, then the main activity is invoked. Now, if I task-switch back to the browser and hit "Share" again on a different piece of text, the menu of sharing targets is not displayed. Instead, my main activity is resumed. Not the lookup one (that'd be reasonable), but the main one. `onNewIntent()` is not delivered to neither main activity nor Lookup activity.
`onResume()` is delivered to main, though.

However, if I tap "Back" instead of task-switching back to the browser - that is, explicitly close my main activity - on the next try, the Share operation displays the menu of targets again.

What's up with this behavior? Does the Share functionality remember the target of the last share operation and try to reuse it? If so, why won't it remember the immediate target of the share - my lookup activity? Is this documented?

EDIT: the manifest for the lookup activity goes like this:

```
 <activity android:name=".Lookup"
        android:label="@string/IDS_LOOKUPTITLE"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I start main activity from lookup activity, I'm trying to reuse an existing one (if any), so the flags are `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Comment: can you post the Manifest file for your app. I guess you have added some kind of launchmode. You can check whether your behavior matches whats described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode